# ubuntu проблемы запуска

Tags: ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Установил VirtualBox на Ubuntu. После перезагрузки перестала загружаться.

```
do_IRQ: 0.55 No irq handler for vector
/dev/sda1: clean, 295142/305315584 files, 12998475/122095872 block
k10temp 0000:00:18.3: unreliable CPU thermal sensor; monitoring
[  OK  ] Started Samba Winbind Daemon.
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Wait Online.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
         Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
         Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring module...
[  OK  ] Started crash report submission daemon.
         Starting Process error reports when automatic reporting is
         Starting Tool to automatically coll... submit kernel crash s
         Starting TeamViewer remote control daemon...
[  OK  ] Started Tool to automatically colle...nd submit kernel crash
[  OK  ] Created slice User Slice of gdm.
[  OK  ] Started Session c1 of user gdm.
         Starting User Manager for UID 121...
[  OK  ] Started LSB: dist temperature monitoring daemon.
[  OK  ] Started User Manager for UID 121.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
See 'systemctl status virtualbox.service' for details.
[  OK  ]Started TeamViewer remote control daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
See 'systemctl status networkd-dispathcer.service' for details.
         Starting Daemon for power management...
[  OK  ] Started Daemon for power management.
^[[B
```

Comment: Alt+F2, логиньтесь в терминале и удаляйте обратно, например

Comment: Не получается, экран вечно обновляется

Comment: Тогда загружаться с LiveCD/LiveUSB, chroot'иться в сломанную систему и удалять обратно, например. Инстукций на эту тему в интернете вроде много (обычно в контексте восстановления загрузчика grub, но суть chroot в целом та же самая для любых задач)